# MIPS floating-point: swc1 vs. s.s

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

I'm doing some work involving `MIPS` assembly, and I keep coming across these four floating-point load/store pseudoinstructions: `l.s`, `l.d`, `s.s`, `s.d`. I found some documentation online and figured out that there are four "actual" instructions that seem to do the same thing: `lwc1`, `ldc1`, `swc1`, and `sdc1`.

My only question is, what's the difference? As far as I can tell, both sets of instructions do exactly the same thing. Do the pseudos maybe exist just because they're easier to read?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My only question is, what's the difference? As far as I can tell, both sets of instructions do exactly the same thing.

Yes, you're right. The only difference that could appear is when a pseudo-instruction is translated to more than one "real" instruction.

> Do the pseudos maybe exist just because they're easier to read?

Again, yes. That's **why** they exist. They give the illusion of a more expressive instruction set. Quoting [Computer organization and design / Patterson & Hennessy](http://books.google.com.py/books?id=1lD9LZRcIZ8C&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=translate+pseudoinstruction+mips&source=bl&ots=o5A1raCiLD&sig=IotEaTSX_BlOigOSwJCeyrXO4yw&hl=es&ei=645nSu_VAYWBtwfLpbn1Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4):

> ... the assembler can also treat common variations of machine language instructions as if they were instructions in their own right. The hardware need not implement these instructions; however, their appearance in assembly language simplifies translation and programming. ...

Given your example, it's more "clear" to say:

```
l.s $f2, 24(t1)       # Load Single contained in 24(t1) to $f2
```

than

```
lwc1 $f2, 24(t1)      # Load Word into Coprocessor 1 from 24(t1) to $f2
```

(Those comments are just expanding how a human would read the asm mnemonic and operands, therefore *not* useful comments to actually write.  From another PoV, you could say that `lwc1` might actually merit a comment like `# load single` while `l.s` is self-explanatory.)

---

Similarly for integer, you can understand better:

```
move $7, $18        # move contents of $18 to $7
```

than

```
add $7, $18, $0
```

For me, it's just be helped by mnemonics to get better legible code.

Answer (score 3):

Actually i think,

```
LWC1 is Load Word to Co-processor 1
LDC1 is Load Double Word to Co-processor 1
```

etc...

---

Guess what, I hit on a Patent page trying to remember these.

[**US Patent 5555384**](http://www.patentstorm.us/patents/5555384/description.html) - Rescheduling conflicting issued instructions by delaying one conflicting instruction into the same pipeline stage as a third non-conflicting instruction

> There are two types of load instructions implemented by FPC 20:
>   LWC1 (Load Word Coprocessor 1, shown in FIG. 4) and
>   LDC1 (Load Double Word Coprocessor 1, shown in FIG. 8).
>
> LWC1 loads a 32-bit word from the memory subsystem into the FPC general registers.
>   LDC1 loads a 64-bit double word from the memory subsystem into the FPC general registers.

which confirms it.
(btw: don't bother to search for the figures referred here unless you
have access to the site).

Comment: Thanks, but I understood that already (those are listed in the official documentation). Perhaps I should've been more clear, but my question was the difference between the pseudoinstruction version of each load/store single/double instruction and the actual version (lwc1 vs l.s, ldc1 vs l.d, etc.).

Comment: I would expect the reason for the psudocode and instruction-set name is for simplicity and portability of the psudocode across variations in ISA.